# How to used Handler and boost::asio::async_result

Tags: c++, boost-asio

How to used boost::asio::async_result, why my code crash with  (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

```
using ReadSignature = void(int);
template <class CompletionToken>
BOOST_ASIO_INITFN_RESULT_TYPE(CompletionToken , ReadSignature)
AsyncRead(boost::asio::io_service* ios,CompletionToken&& token) {
  using Handler = typename boost::asio::handler_type<CompletionToken,
                                                 ReadSignature>::type;
  Handler handler(std::forward<CompletionToken>(token));
  boost::asio::async_result<Handler> result(handler);

  std::cout << std::time(nullptr) << ":before thread" << std::endl;

  std::thread thread([ios,&handler]() {
    std::cout << std::time(nullptr) << ":run in thread before sleep"<< std::endl;
    sleep(5);
    std::cout << std::time(nullptr) << ":run in thread after sleep"<< std::endl;
    std::cout << std::time(nullptr) << ":run in thread before cb" << std::endl;
    ios->post([&handler](){
      handler(2);
    });
    std::cout << std::time(nullptr) << ":run in thread after cb"<<std::endl;
  });
  thread.detach();
  return result.get();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  boost::asio::io_service s;
  boost::asio::io_service::work worker(s);
  boost::asio::spawn(s,[&s](boost::asio::yield_context yield){
    boost::system::error_code er;
    int val=AsyncRead(&s,yield[er]);
    std::cout << std::time(nullptr) <<"get:"<<val<< "" << std::endl;
  });

  s.run();
  return 0;
}
```

I expect : return result.get(); will yield fiber, and value 2 will get.
but the code crash with:(interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV) ,because handler.ec is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By this

```
ios->post([&handler](){
      handler(2);
    });
```

you create lambda which is queued in `io_service`. This closure is executed inside `io_service::run`. You capture by reference `handler` which is local inside `AsyncRead`.
When `handler(2)` is called

```
AsyncRead(&s,yield[er]);
```

coroutine is resumed in above line, `result.get()` is called from `AsyncRead`, `AsyncRead` ends and handler as local variable is destroyed but closure which is executed in `io_service::run` still refers to this variable - undefined behaviour.

You need to capture handler by value, moving it into thread and lambda:

```
  std::thread thread([ios,handler = std::move(handler)]() {
    std::cout << std::time(nullptr) << ":run in thread before sleep"<< std::endl;
    sleep(5);
    std::cout << std::time(nullptr) << ":run in thread after sleep"<< std::endl;
    std::cout << std::time(nullptr) << ":run in thread before cb" << std::endl;
    ios->post([handler = std::move(handler)]() mutable {
      handler(2);
    });
    std::cout << std::time(nullptr) << ":run in thread after cb"<<std::endl;
  });
```

Comment: 'result.get();' will yield AsyncRead, Why   local variable 'handler"  is destroyed?

Comment: This `Handler handler(std::forward<CompletionToken>(token));` creates `handler` as local variable inside `AsyncRead` function. When the following closure `[&handler](){ handler(2); });`  is performed, it calls `handler(2)`, then `result.get()` returns 2, `AsyncRead` functions ends and `handler` as local variable of `AsyncRead` is destroyed. But you still refer inside closure to this variable because you capture it by reference - it is dangling reference. `handler` must be moved or copied into closure to prolong its lifetime.

Comment: I add sleep after `result.get()`, also crash.

`int val = result.get();
  std::cout << std::time(nullptr) << ":after get ===" << std::endl;
  boost::asio::deadline_timer t(*ios, boost::posix_time::seconds(2));
  t.async_wait(std::forward<CompletionToken>(token));
  return val; `

Comment: I add sleep after `result.get()`, AsyncRead will ends after 2 seconds, So thread can exit first,but also crash.

Comment: @ZhigangZhang Please, can you unaccept my answer ? , then I will be able to delete it because I would like to do it. There are many things with `boost::asio::spawn` i.e. like coroutines play the role here. You can run your application under debugger, and you will see what happens. It is not just simple as you think. Also boost asio reference is so needy. I answered you what I know, but I see it is not enough.

Comment: Crash occurs on `*ec_=..` in  class handler when ec_ equal 0.    And I use `watch point` to find who change the value:     `[New Thread 0x7fa915f4a700 (LWP 7970)]

Thread 1 "test1" hit Hardware watchpoint 3: *0x1ed82e8

Old value = 32342816
New value = 0
0x00007fa916c69477 in _Unwind_Resume () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1  `     What is _Unwind_Resume?  Why it change the value ?

Comment: ` unwind` is called by `if ( from->do_unwind) throw forced_unwind();`   in  `push_coroutine_impl::push`